# having issue with Route & Link in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a React project in which I use the Switch, Link and Route from react-router-dom to route to the paths. but now I'm facing an issue and in console I'm getting errors **The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`** and  **cannot read property history of undefined** which is pointing to Link.js line number 76 . When i checked Link.js, there is a line where this.context.router.history is used, and seems like this.context.router is undefined. Couldn't figure out whats the real issue as this was working till yesterday. The version of react-router-dom I'm using is 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some code example?
It seems like you are putting  outside of BrowserRouter's scope (or HashRouter's). 
 must always be inside the scope of .

You **can** do this:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Link ... />
        <Layout>

            <Switch>
                <Route ... />
                <Route ... />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>`
```

But you **cannot** do something like this:

```
<Link ... />
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>

        <Switch>
            <Route ... />
            <Route ... />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
    </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>`
```

User Kishan Jaiswal is pointing you in the right direction by the way, he's linking to an issue which wasn't a bug but only a misplaced Link component outside of react-router-dom Router.

Answer (score 0):

just take a reference of this and match your route file 
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4759